# DocuSign "Time Zone Used For API" In New DocuSign Experience

Tags: docusignapi

I have a DocuSign Connect integration written using the SOAP API.  All time zones in the XML sent by DocuSign is in PST, but I need this to be in CST.  I was able to find the "Time Zone Used For API" setting in my demo account and this resolved the issue in my demo account.  I cannot find this same setting within the production account using the New DocuSign Experience.

Is there any way to change the timezone for the SOAP API using the New DocuSign Experience?

Answer (score 0):

For DocuSign Connect, you will need to ask your account manager to adjust a setting called "*Time Zone used for Connect and SOAP*". This is not available for you to adjust yourself.